# How to get filename from UploadFileCompletedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, webclient

My goal is to get the filename of the finished file from e.

```
...
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(address, "STOR", filename));
...

    void WebClientUploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //How to get filename from e?
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `webClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(address), "STOR", filename);`? Uri has no constructor taking a string as third parameter

Comment: e.Result contains server reponse. Write it to file and name it with filename

Comment: @Ata the question is asking what is the filename, not the content.

Comment: @VERYNET No...........

Comment: @KooKiz it is about e not the syntax of webclient.

Comment: @VitalisHommel My answer won't work otherwise, that's why I'm asking ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`UploadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144234(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a user state as fourth parameter. So you can change the call to:

```
webClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(address), "STOR", filename, filename);
```

And retrieve it in the callback:

```
void WebClientUploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var filename = (string)e.UserState;
}
```